# Javascript ForEach on Array of Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I am looping through a collection of blog posts to firstly push the username and ID of the blog author to a new array of arrays, and then secondly, count the number of blogs from each author. The code below achieves this; however, in the new array, the username and author ID are no longer separate items in the array, but seem to be concatenated into a single string. I need to retain them as separate items as I need to use both separately; how can I amend the result to achieve this?

```
    var countAuthors = [];
    blogAuthors = await Blog.find().populate('authors');
    blogAuthors.forEach(function(blogAuthor){
        countAuthors.push([blogAuthor.author.username, blogAuthor.author.id]);
        
    })
    console.log(countAuthors);
    // Outputs as separate array items, as expected:
    //   [ 'author1', 5d7eed028c298b424b3fb5f1 ],
    //   [ 'author2', 5dd8aa254d74b30017dbfdd3 ],
    var result = {};
    countAuthors.forEach(function(x) {
        result[x] = (result[x] || 0) + 1;
    });

    console.log(result);
    //  Username and author ID become a single string and cannot be accessed as separate array items
    //  'author1,5d7eed028c298b424b3fb5f1': 15,
    //  'author2,5dd8aa254d74b30017dbfdd3': 2,
```

**Update:**

Maybe I can explain a bit further WHY on what to do this.  What I am aiming for is a table which displays the blog author's name alongside the number of blogs they have written.  However, I also want the author name to link to their profile page, which requires the blogAuthor.author.id to do so.  Hence, I need to still be able to access the author username and ID separately after executing the count. Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what you're expecting. `result[x] = ...` is trying to set property `x` of `result`, and in this case `x` is an array. You want an object *keyed* by arrays? Such a thing isn't possible in javascript.

Comment: Or do you want an object with both author and id keys? In other words `{ "author1": 15, "author1,5d7eed028c298b424b3fb5f1": 15, "author2": 2, "5dd8aa254d74b30017dbfdd3": 2 }`?

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you weren't splitting the `x` up in the foreach callback, and so the whole array was being converted to a string and being used as the key when inserting into the results object.

You can use array destructuring to split the author name and blog id, and use them to optionally adding a new entry to the result object, and then update that result.

```js
countAuthors = [
  ['author1', 'bookId1'],
  ['author2', 'bookId2'],
  ['author1', 'bookId3'],
  ['author1', 'bookId4'],
  ['author2', 'bookId5']
]

var result = {};

countAuthors.forEach(([author, id]) => {
  if (result[author] === undefined) {
    result[author] = {count: 0, blogIds: []};
  }
  result[author].count += 1;
  result[author].blogIds.push(id);
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thanks I was assuming something along this line, though when I console.log the result like this, it only seems to return like { 'author1': 2,
  'author2': 1 }, i don't see the ID being returned at all in result?

Comment: Sorry I didn't see the bit about wanting to keep the ids in a sub-array. I have updated my answer: have a look at the object being added and then updated now!

Comment: Thanks this seems to be getting closer, though I had to remove `If (result[author] === undefined) {`as it was throwing the error, 'cannot read property push of undefined'. Can I please understand why you included that line?  If I remove it, the output is: 1{ 'author1': { count: 1, blogIds: [ 5dd8abe24d74b30017dbfdd6 ] },
  author2: { count: 1, blogIds: [ 5ec4a45872954100170363dd ] }`.  While all the elements are there, the count is returning as 1 for every record rather than the correct number.  Also, how would I then access each element individually?

Answer (score 0):

You could use String.split().
For example:

```
let result = 'author1,5d7eed028c298b424b3fb5f1'.split(',')
```

would set result to:

```
['author1' , '5d7eed028c298b424b3fb5f1']
```

You can then access them individually like:

```
result[1] //'5d7eed028c298b424b3fb5f1'
```

Comment: Thanks I did think about splitting - however, there is a possibility that the author usernames would have commas in them as well, which complicates this solution.